# Trying to set values with HTML tags in radio input tags

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

In React, I have an array of objects and I wish to use superscript on a particular index. I want set the value to a state variable but it seems the state can not detect the value because it sees a HTML tag and not a string. How can I solve this?
questions:
{
question:

A right triangle has sides that are consecutive even integers. The longest
side is z. Which of the following equations could be used to find z?

,
options: [(z-4) <sup>2</sup> = z <sup>2</sup> - (z-2) <sup>2</sup>,
(z-2) <sup>2</sup> = z <sup>2</sup> - (z-4),
z <sup>2</sup> = z <sup>2</sup> - z-4 <sup>2</sup>,
z <sup>2</sup> = (z-1) <sup>2</sup> + (z-2) <sup>2</sup> ],
answer: (z-4) <sup>2</sup> = z <sup>2</sup> - (z-2) <sup>2</sup>
}
React component:

```
<div id="inputs">
       <div><input type="radio" name="options" value={answerList[0]} onChange={changeValue} 
       checked={radioValue == answerList[0]}/><label>{answerList[0]}</label></div>
       <div><input type="radio" name="options" value={answerList[1]} onChange={changeValue} 
       checked={radioValue == answerList[1]}/><label>{answerList[1]}</label></div>
       <div><input type="radio" name="options" value={answerList[2]} onChange={changeValue} 
       checked={radioValue == answerList[2]}/><label>{answerList[2]}</label></div>
       <div><input type="radio" name="options" value={answerList[3]} onChange={changeValue} 
       checked={radioValue == answerList[3]}/><label>{answerList[3]}</label></div>
       </div>
```

Comment: ( If you didn't intend to format the way I edited, please revert the edit )

Comment: There is [an equation renderer for React](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-equation) that you may find useful.

Comment: @adiga No my initial question was correct, I just took the part of the array of object I am having issues with.

Comment: @Andy I have tried that but still same issue, the major issue is how I can render superscripts in react and setting the value of the radio checked in state